# Can you Unzip and view content on Google App engine - Python?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, csv, zip

I am trying to upload large CSV files onto GAE using a zip using XML & HTTP POST

Steps:

- CSV is zipped & base64 encoded and sent to GAE via XML/HTTP POST
- GAE - using minidom to parse XML
- GAE - Base64 decode ZIP
- GAE - Get CSV from Zip file.

I have tried using zipfile but can't figure out how to create a zipfile object from the base 64decoded string

I get: TypeError: unbound method read() must be called with ZipFile instance as first argument (got str instance instead)

```
myZipFile = base64.decodestring(base64ZipFile)

objZip = zipfile.ZipFile(myZipFile,'r')

strCSV = zipfile.ZipFile.read(objZip,'list.csv')
```

Comment: There's really no reason at all to base64 encode the file in the first place.

Comment: @NickJohnson: I think the base64 encode is in there because Bezerk is enclosing it in XML, but that could probably be skipped too (unless there is more in the XML than just the zipped CSV file).

Comment: Well, that makes it even more pointless. :)

Comment: I do it out of habit with XML/http post. I have had issues with outher files over the years.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As Rob mentioned, `ZipFile` requires a file-like object. You can use [`StringIO`](http://docs.python.org/library/stringio.html) to provide a file-like interface to a string.

For example:

```
import StringIO

myZipFile = base64.decodestring(base64ZipFile)

objZip = zipfile.ZipFile(StringIO.StringIO(myZipFile),'r')
```

Comment: Thanks. I used something similar to your suggestion and it worked.

Answer (score 2):

Yes you can. In fact, I wrote a blog post that [describes how to do exactly that](http://blog.notdot.net/2010/08/Using-BlobReader-wildcard-subdomains-and-webapp2).

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply.

Answer (score 1):

A simple approach might be to upload the zipped csv to the blobstore using the [blob upload API](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/blobstore/overview.html#Uploading_a_Blob), and process the zip file from there. You'd need to fake a form post, but life might be simpler for you on the appengine side.

There's an example of how to process zipped data in [AppEngine MapReduce](http://code.google.com/p/appengine-mapreduce). See the [BlobstoreZipInputReader](http://code.google.com/p/appengine-mapreduce/source/browse/trunk/python/src/mapreduce/input_readers.py#834) class.

Answer (score 0):

[`ZipFile`](http://docs.python.org/library/zipfile.html#zipfile-objects) does not take a string but a file-like object.

One solution is creating a [`tempfile`](http://docs.python.org/library/tempfile.html) to write the string to then passing that to `ZipFile`:

```
import tempfile
import zipfile

tmp = tempfile.TemporaryFile()
tmp.write(myZipFile) # myZipFile is your decoded string containing the zip-data
objZip = zipfile.ZipFile(tmp)
```

Comment: Unfortunately app engine doesn't allow creation of temporary files.

Comment: @SaxonDruce, I was under the impression you could you use `TemporaryFile` but not `NamedTemporaryFile`. [Quick google seems to confirm](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/runtime.html#Pure_Python). I have not tried it myself however.

Comment: Ah I see "tempfile is disabled, except for TemporaryFile which is aliased to StringIO" - I hadn't noticed that before :)

Comment: This would also require reading the whole of the blob into memory, which is a bad idea, given there's already a blobreader API that gives you a file-like object.

Comment: @NickJohnson, except the whole blob already *is* in memory. Thanks for the downvote though.

Comment: @RobWouters Only if you don't use the blobstore. The blobstore is ideally suited to this, since it's designed for uploading and manipulating large files. I downvoted you because you suggest a solution that explicitly isn't supported on App Engine except through a hack, such that what you're doing is the same as using StringIO, only with more obfuscation.

Comment: @NickJohnson: All right, fair enough. I only later realized `TemporaryFile` was an alias for `StringIO`.

Comment: I'm happy to remove the downvote if you edit your answer to use StringIO. I still don't think it's a _good_ idea, but at least it's not an awful one. ;)